# How to joint lines in if condition?

Tags: python

When I use backslash (`\`) to join conditions in `if` condition, code does not compile. How to join this?

My code is on **Python colab**:

```
a = 0
b = 1
c= 2
d = 3
e = 4
f = 5
if  a == 0 and b>0 \   
    and e >=3 and f <=5 :
        print("Jointing  ")
```

Comment: You have spaces after the \

Answer (score 2):

To have multiline if statements you can use parenthesis

```
if (a == 0 and b > 0
    and e >= 3 and f <= 5):
        print("Jointing  ")
```

or as khelwood mentioned, remove the trailing spaces after the `\`

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand your question, but if you want to do something like:

```
"if x == 5 OR y==3"
```

Then you can use the `or` keyword in python:

```
if x==5 or y==3:
   #Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Its important to include the error in your question. Running your code gives

```
  File "test.py", line 7
    if  a == 0 and b>0 \   
                          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

The backslash escapes the next character. To escape a newline, the backslash must be the last thing on the line. Fixing that, your code works.

Answer (score 0):

[PEP8 says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

```
if (a == 0 and b > 0 
    and e >= 3 and f <= 5):
    print("Jointing  ")
```